# Oscillator in Langton's ant

Tags: co.combinatorics, ds.dynamical-systems, discrete-geometry, cellular-automata

First of all, see [Langton's ant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langton%27s_ant) Wikipedia page.

If we place a pair of ants looking north (using Golly or any another prog) on the coordinates $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ under the conditions:

- $p=|x_1-x_2|$, $q=|y_1-y_2|$,
- $p$ odd, $q$ even,

then I conjecture that, if the pair of ants constitutes an oscillator, its periodicity has the form $4(2n+1)$.

Is there some intuition behind this? Is there a way to prove it?

Comment: The question seems interesting. Since you seem to lack both an intuition and a proof of this, I assume the conjecture comes from some numerical simulation of the automaton, right? If so, could you please tell something more on these results?